# Any example using firebase-document

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I need to fetch data from a Firebase using `firebase-document`. I need to further process the data *after* I receive the response payload. How do I do this?

[I read the documentation here, but there are no examples](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/firebase-document). I see there is a property called `transactionsComplete` but, again, no examples. Since it's a `promise`, I am uncertain how to implement it.

Can someone please provide a working code example of how to use the properties or methods of `firebase-document` to process the data returned by the request and *after* the transaction is complete?

```
<firebase-document
    id="doc"
    app-name="my-app">
</firebase-document>
<script>
  _userChanged: function(u) {
    if(u) {
      var doc = this.$.doc;
      var path = [ 'users' , u.uid ].join('/');
      doc.path = path; // this should send a request for data
      // but how do I ensure to process what is returned
      // after and only after it comes back?
    }                   
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the an object to the property `data="{{object}}"` then you can add an `observer` or computed property that will return the final value

```
<firebase-document
  path="/users/{{userId}}/notes/{{noteId}}"
  data="{{noteData}}">
</firebase-document>
```

Using `firebase-focument` method `getStoredValue(path);` (ES6 Style)

```
  this.$.doc.getStoredValue(path)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- setup firebase-document (node) -->
<firebase-document
  path="/dummy"
  data="{{dummy}}">
</firebase-document>

<paper-input 
  id="dummy"
  name="dummy"
  label="Dummy Text"
  value={{dummy.text}}>
</paper-input>
```

or you could use `this.dummy` inside a `javascript` `function` to access the variable.

Since it is using the data-binding of Polymer, value will be then updated to firebase.